# modal element not displayed from init

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, show

All,

I have a modal element being loaded through a router, the issue happens when i try to show the modal, it does not show up, though the URL is properly changed. The issues does not appear if i invoke the init happens within a $timeout with a delay of some time. I do not want to specify the delay time, any suggestions, to do away with $timeout and delay time.

Here is my code

```
(function init() {
      $scope.model = {
    //    email specific info being set here
      };


      $timeout(function() {
        modalElement = angular.element('[ng-controller="mycontroller"] .modal');
         modalElement.modal('show');

      },50); // without this delay the modal element is not shown
    })();
```

Note that this issue happens only the first time the modal is loaded after a refresh, once the modal is set in the cache this issue does not happen, possibly the delay in fetching the modal causing this issue.

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
used the interval and tried to check the availability of the modal object before invoking the show, did the trick. hence it can be like 

    var test =  $interval(function() {
      modalElement = angular.element('[ng-controller="mycontroller"] .modal');
        if(modalElement.length ==1)
        {
            modalElement.modal('show');
            $interval.cancel(test);
        }
          },50); // without this delay the modal element is not shown
```